# Adding Parameters to get_comment

Tags: comments, parameter

I have a code like this:

```
<?php $comments = get_comments( 'post_id=' . $post->ID ); echo get_comment_author($comments[0]->comment_ID); ?>
<br />
<?php $comments = get_comments( 'post_id=' . $post->ID ); echo get_comment_date('d F H:i', $comments[0]->comment_ID); ?>
```

and i want to include `'approve' - approved` comments into this code.

I am familiar with this code:

```
<?php $defaults = array(
    'ID' => '',
    'number' => '1',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'status' => 'approved',
); ?>
```

But I am unable to integrate both codes.

My point is: show posts last commenter name and comment date `d F H:i` together. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> My point is: show posts last commenter name and comment date d F H:i
>   together. Any suggestions?

I think what you want is:

```
$defaults = array(
    'post_id' => $post->ID,
    'number' => '1',
    'orderby' => 'comment_date_gmt ', // default value; not really necessary
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'status' => 'approved',
);
```

You shouldn't need to run `get_comments()` twice.

```
$defaults = array(
    'post_id' => 120,
    'number' => '1',
    'orderby' => 'comment_date_gmt ', // default value; not really necessary
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'status' => 'approved',
);
$comments = get_comments($defaults);
if (!empty($comments[0])) {
  $comments = $comments[0];
  comment_author($comments->comment_ID);
  comment_date('d F H:i', $comments->comment_ID);
}
```